# Firing multiple soap requests with different data through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, soapui

I want to fire multiple soap requests with **different data** through jmeter and I want all the soap requests to hit the application concurrently. Also I would like to know if I can do the same thing with soap ui? If possible do describe the steps in detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JMeter:

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your test plan
2. Add Switch to "Body Data" tab and put your XML payload skeleton there
3. Substitute the parts of the body you want to parameterise with [JMeter Variables or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), the most commonly used for parameterisation test elements are:

   - [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
   - [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)
   - [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
   - [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead)
4. For "concurrency" you also have different options:

   - If you want X threads to execute requests as fast as they can - just specify them in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
   - If you want X requests per second - go for [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
   - If you want all requests at exactly the same time - [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

For SoapUI check out [Simulating Different Types of Load](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/simulating-different-types-of-load.html) article